# Product between two dynamic-sized Eigen matrices of customized scalar types

Tags: eigen

I have two customized scalar types `T` and `S`. I overloaded the matrix product `operator*` between Eigen matrix of `T` and `S`, as suggested in [Mixing Scalar Types in Eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494288/mixing-scalar-types-in-eigen)

```cpp
template <typename MatrixL, typename MatrixR>
typename std::enable<(std::is_same<MatrixL::Scalar, T>::value && std::is_same<MatrixR::Scalar,S>::value) || (std::is_same<MatrixR::Scalar, T>::value && std::is_same<MatrixL::Scalar, S>::value), Eigen::Matrix<T, MatrixL::RowsAtCompileTime, MatrixR::ColsAtCompileTime>::type
operator*(const MatrixL& lhs, const MatrixR& rhs) {
  return lhs.template cast<T>() * rhs.template cast<T>();
}
```

I found I can multiply a static-sized matrix with another static-sized one, or static-sized matrix multiplies with a dynamic sized matrix. But the compiler would fail for dynamic sized matrix multiplying another dynamic sized one.

```cpp
Eigen::Matrix<T, 2, 2> T_static;
Eigen::Matrix<T, Dynamic, Dynamic> T_dynamic(2, 2);
Eigen::Matrix<S, 2, 2> S_static;
Eigen::Matrix<S, Dynamic, Dynamic> S_dynamic(2, 2);
T_static * S_static;    // works
T_static * S_dynamic;   // works
T_dynamic * S_static;   // works
T_dynamic * S_dynamic;  // compilation error
```

The error I got looks like

```
external/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/products/GeneralBlockPanelKernel.h:435:28: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
external/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/products/GeneralBlockPanelKernel.h:1413:13: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter 'AccPacketType' ('drake::symbolic::RationalFunction' and 'Eigen::internal::gebp_kernel<drake::symbolic::RationalFunction, drake::symbolic::Polynomial, long int, Eigen::internal::blas_data_mapper<drake::symbolic::RationalFunction, long int, 0, 0>, 2, 4, false, false>::RhsPacket {aka drake::symbolic::Polynomial}')
             EIGEN_GEBGP_ONESTEP(6);
             ^
external/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/products/GeneralBlockPanelKernel.h:1413:13: error: no matching function for call to 'Eigen::internal::gebp_traits<drake::symbolic::RationalFunction, drake::symbolic::Polynomial, false, false>::madd(Eigen::internal::gebp_kernel<drake::symbolic::RationalFunction, drake::symbolic::Polynomial, long int, Eigen::internal::blas_data_mapper<drake::symbolic::RationalFunction, long int, 0, 0>, 2, 4, false, false>::LhsPacket&, Eigen::internal::gebp_kernel<drake::symbolic::RationalFunction, drake::symbolic::Polynomial, long int, Eigen::internal::blas_data_mapper<drake::symbolic::RationalFunction, long int, 0, 0>, 2, 4, false, false>::RhsPacket&, Eigen::internal::gebp_kernel<drake::symbolic::RationalFunction, drake::symbolic::Polynomial, long int, Eigen::internal::blas_data_mapper<drake::symbolic::RationalFunction, long int, 0, 0>, 2, 4, false, false>::AccPacket&, Eigen::internal::gebp_kernel<drake::symbolic::RationalFunction, drake::symbolic::Polynomial, long int, Eigen::internal::blas_data_mapper<drake::symbolic::RationalFunction, long int, 0, 0>, 2, 4, false, false>::RhsPacket&)'
             EIGEN_GEBGP_ONESTEP(6);
```

where `drake::symbolic::Polynomial` is type `S`, and `drake::symbolic::RationalFunction` is type `T`. I use llvm-4.0 on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

Comment: As a workaround, do `T_dynamic .lazyProduct( S_dynamic )`, this will call the same path as for the static versions.

Comment: Thanks! `lazyProduct` works.